# Redux-saga is not running in my reactJS App

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have my very simple test saga :

```
 export function* helloSaga() {
    console.log('Hello Sagas!')
}
```

Here is how I call it :

```
 import reducer from "./Redux/rootReducer";
import {helloSaga} from "./Redux/Sagas/saga";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
export const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() // chrome devtools thing
);
```

`sagaMiddleware.run(helloSaga())`

But I'm getting error that `× Error: runSaga(options, saga, ...args): saga argument must be a Generator function!`. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you pass the result of generator function instead of function itself as following:

```js
sagaMiddleware.run(helloSaga)
```